# Want to build a Floating Table like that

Tags: tables

I'm bulding a table to describe a register of DMA. So I can't take a float table with number of column can be configured. Help me if you can. Thank you so much.
[image]

Comment: There are many possible solutions, a tabular with five lines and about 19 columns, e.g. But without an MWE it is really difficult to decide what will help you and which effort will be wasted. So please provide an MWE, like you did in your other question.

Comment: You can put tabulars into figures and pictures into tables.  The only difference is the caption.  (If I had designed it I would have merged table and figure and used \captionof for everything.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just as an example, how you could start...

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{array, lmodern, calc, ragged2e, textcomp}
\newlength{\bruch}
\setlength{\bruch}{3mm}
\newlength{\lange}
\setlength{\lange}{8\bruch}
\newcommand{\field}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{>{\Centering}p{\bruch}|}{#1}}
\newcommand{\tda}{\textdownarrow}
\newcommand{\tdu}{\textuparrow}
\newcommand{\fnt}[1]{\footnotesize{}#1}

\begin{document}
\begin{addmargin}[-1cm]{0pt}\sffamily{}
  \begin{tabular}{*{2}{p{\lange}}*{16}{>{\Centering}p{\bruch}}}
 & & \fnt{RSVD} & & \fnt{Irq} && \fnt{RSVD} &&\fnt{SGS}&&& \fnt{DMAD}&&\fnt{DMA}&&\fnt{RSVD}&&Hallo!\\
 & & \tda & & \tda && \tda&&\tda&&& \tda&&\tda&&\tda&&\tda\\
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|p{\lange}|}{31 \hfill 24}&\multicolumn{1}{p{\lange}|}{23 \hfill{} 16}
&\field{15}&\field{14}&\field{13}&\field{12}&\field{11}&\field{10}&\field{9}&\field{8}&
\field{7}&\field{6}&\field{5}&\field{4}&\field{3}&\field{2}&\field{1}&\field{0}\\
\hline{}
$\underbrace{\hspace{\lange}}$ & $\underbrace{\hspace{\lange}}$ 
 & & \tdu&&\tdu&&\tdu&&\tdu&\tdu&&\tdu&&\tdu&&\tdu\\
More Text & More Text & \multicolumn{5}{l}{and so on \dots{}}\\
  \end{tabular}
\end{addmargin}

\end{document}
```

[image: result of tabular]